# How to open multi UIwebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

In UIWebView 1 click a hyperlink then open UIWebView 2, click a hyperlink in UIWebView 2 then open UIWebView 3, click a hyperlink in UIWebView 3 then open UIWebView 4....

How to implement this?

I now open a second UIWebView in

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
self.otherWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    numberOfOpenedWebPage ++;
    self.otherWebView.tag = numberOfOpenedWebPage;

    self.otherWebView.delegate = self;
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    self.otherWebView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.size.width, 0.0f, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:self.otherWebView];
    [otherWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Because every new webview need to share the delegate method, so I defined uiwebview var as class var. But I donno how to create more in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`

Thanks

Comment: You can identify the web view via the `webView` argument passed in, then you can do whatever you want.

Comment: more details please? I'm confusing now ... You mean tag? I did, but seems not correct...

Comment: Can you the code of the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you don't check where the hyperlink is opened from.

You should rewrite the code according to this pseudocode:

```
// Declare a NSMutableArray in the .h file to store all UIWebViews that are loaded this way.
// Assume that I can refer to it as self.allWebViews
// Set tag of the first UIWebView to 0, and put it in self.allWebViews

if (self.allWebViews.count <= webView.tag + 1) {
    Initialize a new UIWebView
    Set tag to self.allWebViews.count
    Add it to self.allWebViews
    Subview the UIWebView
    Set it to load NSURLRequest passed in
} else {
    Get the UIWebView from the (webView.tag + 1) position of the self.allWebViews
    Set the UIWebView to load the NSURLRequest passed in
}

// Never load hyperlink in the current web view
return NO;
```

Note that the UIWebViews are held by strong reference from the NSMutableArray. I am not sure how your program works, but you have to take note of this to release the UIWebView if you don't use it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll try it later, whatever I got, will update you.